# Row with data deletion after time expires

Tags: python, flask

I need to record my IP addresses, names and time the IP addresses are sent to a database.
Tell me how to implement a function to delete from the database as soon as the time that I used expires. Created on Flask.

Code:

`html:`

IP Address:

```
<label for="block_period">Amount of Block:</label>
<select id="block_period" name="block_period">
  <option value="1 hour">1 Hour</option>
  <option value="24 hours">24 Hours</option>
  <option value="3 days">3 Days</option>
  <option value="1 week">1 Week</option>
  <option value="1 month">1 Month</option>
</select><br>

<label for="user">User:</label>
<select id="user" name="user">
    <option value="user3">user3</option>
    <option value="user4">user4</option>
    <option value="user5">user5</option>
</select><br>

  <button id="submitButton">Block</button>
```

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/block', methods=['POST'])
def block():
    ip_address = request.form['ip_address']
    block_period = request.form['block_period']
    user = request.form['user']

    add_to_database(ip_address, block_period, user)

    return 'Data successfully added to database!'


def add_to_database(ip_address, block_period, user):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ip_blocker.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Create table if it doesn't exist
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocked_ips
                 (ip_address text, block_period text, user text, block_time timestamp)''')

    # Insert data into table
    block_time = datetime.now()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO blocked_ips VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (ip_address, block_period, user, block_time))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # Add IP address to the list of blocked IPs
    blocked_ips.append(ip_address)

    # Start a new thread to remove IP address from the list and database after block period
    t = threading.Thread(target=remove_ip_address, args=(ip_address, block_time))
    t.start()
```

here is the `remove ip address` method for deletion, but it does not work. I select 1 Hour from dropdown list and wait 1 hour but data does not delete. Please assist.

```
def remove_ip_address(ip_address, block_time):
    # Wait for the block period to end
    block_period_seconds = int(block_period) * 60
    time.sleep(block_period_seconds)

    # Remove IP address from the list of blocked IPs
    blocked_ips.remove(ip_address)

    # Remove IP address from the database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ip_blocker.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM blocked_ips WHERE ip_address=?", (ip_address,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # Save IP address to CSV file
    with open('blocked_ips.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([ip_address, block_period, user, block_time])
```

Comment: What happens if you choose 1 second instead of 1 hour? That way you won't have to wait 1 hour to see if it works.

Comment: What happens if you insert some print statements into `remove_ip_address`? Do you see their output?

Comment: @mkrieger1 can you show it on my code?

Comment: @juicy do you think you have provided us with a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @bonCodigo yes. this code is executable